# Include() shows error for 1 entity but not for another

Tags: entity-framework

.Include in Below doesn't work for one entity but it works for another.

```
    public Category GetCategory(int CategoryID)
    {
        return DataSource.Categories
            .Include(c => c.TransCategories)
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.CategoryID == CategoryID);
    }
```

The error is

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

While it works for another entity.

```
    public Question Get(long QuestionID)
    {
        return DataSource.Questions
            .Include(q => q.TransQuestions)
            .Include(q => q.SubCategories)
            .FirstOrDefault(q => q.QuestionID == QuestionID);
    }
```

Comment: are both methods in the same file?  Might just be missing these 2 references `using System.Data;using System.Data.Entity;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the using `System.Data.Entity` to your first file.

`.Include()` has an extension method that accepts a lambda expression that you can find in the `System.Data.Entity` namespace.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx).

Comment: Upvoted - Most likely a missing reference as you say

Comment: wowwwww it worked, yeah this namespace was not added in this file, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two methods are in different files, it could be as simple as missing references. Go through the using statements and check all there relevant ones are there for your referenced extension methods.

Comment: because it wasn't the solution

Comment: I was in the middle of listing all the references you would need to make your code sample work. Anyway - glad you got it working. I've updated my answer to a generic "ensure all references are included".